# Is chess game movement TM decidable?

Tags: turing-machines, automata, undecidability, decision-problem

If we have a finite chess board and two figures x and y. Is it possible to get y from x by following chess rules and when white is y and white starts from y placement. Is this decidable?

My reasoning is, that we have a finite sets of moves  and since all finite languages are decidable and at some point x is going to get y this problem is decidable. What do you think?

Comment: BFS on the graph of all possible positions, where two positions are connect if you can reach from one to the other in a single move (a pretty big graph, but who cares).

Comment: If the size of your board is fixed, it's even decidable in constant time.

Comment: Note that there are cycles in chess. (In particular, even though the 50-move rule exists it requires a player to claim it, and a player may not claim it) As such, you do need to do a proper graph search. Otherwise your TM won't decide the question, just accept it, as in the case of y not being reachable from x it'll potentially get caught in a loop and never halt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The chess board problem is, although complex, a **finite** problem. Specifically, the number of moves, starting from any board position, is finite.

Then, a TM can just go over all the possible moves (there are only $C$ such moves, for some "small" constant $C$), and verify if a certain position is feasible continuation of a prior position. Hence, any such question is decidable.